# Clearing full canvas faster than just parts?

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, html5-canvas

Noticed something I didn't expect when playing with animation in Canvas. I have a fairly easy animation of five images in different sizes moving from bottom to top of screen in a loop.

I have all my image data in an array and draw them onto the canvas via a loop, then use `window.requestAnimationFrame` to do a new draw on next frame.

Here is the interesting part, at first I just cleared the canvas for each frame rendered using `context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`. Then I though that this must be a waste of computing, to clear the entire canvas for each render even thou only parts of the screen actually changed.

So I rewrote the part clearing the canvas to only clear the trace of the old image draw, using something like this:

```
for (var key in _images) {
   context.clearRect(_images[key].x-1, _images[key].y+_images[key].height, _images[key].width+2, 5);
}
```

But too my surprise this seems to be slower... First I had a frame rate at 49-60, and after 47-57. Any idea to why? And is there any other way to optimize this?

Comment: because of the loop, and/or because clearing the whole canvas is optimised better internally, perhaps?

Comment: Each ClearRect takes up roughly the same amount of time, so instead of one ClearRect call you now have three. Your three ClearRect also have a bit of overhead because of the maths and referencing you use.

Comment: You should calculate the rect that you need to clear and then call clearRect only once.  I.E. the union of the images

Comment: So it is always better to clear the entire canvas than many parts of it? But also better to clear as little as possible, so to say if your changes are only in 50% of canvas, its better to only clear 50%.

Comment: its probably 'better' to clear the whole canvas, the GPU takes care of most of this for you. Gains will be marginal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since people answered in comments and I do feel they covered my questions. Here's a summery:

Each `clearRect()` takes up roughly the same amount of time, so it is better to have few than many.

To optimize one should calculate the area that needs to be cleared, if not 100%, and clear that.

Answer (score 2):

0) i would rather write :

```
for (var i=0, len=_images.length; i<len; i++) {
   var thisImage = _images[i];
   context.clearRect(thisImage.x, thisImage.y, thisImage.width, thisImage.height);
}
```

1) when requestAnimationFrame triggers, draw before updating, so you are right in sync with the screen.
2) round the coordinates to the nearest 64 bits, i.e. use &(~3) on each x coordinates can speed things up.
3) You might group some clearRect together (= all the bullets / a tiled horizontal floor, ...)
4) i think the main question here is the overhead of those methods.
I did a jsperf to know more :
http://jsperf.com/overhead-of-fillrect-and-clearrect/2

!! be sure to have the canvas in sight during the tests !!

Results :

**Firefox**, clearRect has very small overhead, and time seems 
almost proportionnal with pixel count.
fillRect is like 60% slower and seems quite proportionnal also
with area covered.

64 bit Unalignment seems of no effet on clearRect, it makes performances
fall badly on fillRect.

some times from jsPerf (precision is so-so) :

208ns for fullscreen clearRect
55ns for halfscreen clearRect -> 4 times makes 220ns vs 208
13ns for quarter screen clearRect -> 16 times makes 208 (!!!)

588ns fullscreen fillRect
1290ns halfscreen fillRect --> 4 times makes 1160
41ns quarterscreen fillrect --> 16 times makes 656.

**Safari**, everything the results are quite the same, except there is
more overhead : it is only 3 times faster to draw 4 times less points.

I know the the precision is so-so but it seems that on firefox
and Safari, the conclusion is :
**the less part of your screen you clear, the faster you erase**.

- And prefer clearRect to fillRect -

**Chrome** : (date 05 / 14) fillRect is much faster than clearRect.

**IE11** : fillRect and clearRect are on par.

((If anyone can see on other Browser, i'll edit -when i have some time-))

( provided your images are 4 pixels aligned, the code with
64 align is :

```
for (var i=0, len=_images.length; i<len; i++) {
   var thisImage = _images[i];
   var x = thisImage.x ;
   context.clearRect(x & (~3), thisImage.y, thisImage.width + ((x&3)&&(16-(x&3))), thisImage.height);
}
```

)

Comment: I ran your test. In latest Chrome `fillRect` is way, way faster than `clearRect` (8000 vs. 1,000,000). In IE11, it's about the same (7MM).

Comment: @subkamran : thanks for the update. I think that as long as blink is under development, we'll have strange bugs or performances figures. Not sure i'll take the time to review all current Browser though... i updated with your comments, in fact feel free to edit the post if you want.